# Django Channels 2: How Many Users Is In The Specific Room

Tags: django, sockets, websocket, django-channels, asgi

I am using django-channels>=2.0.0 and I want to find how many users in "room1". I don't know how to find total connections.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `InMemoryChannelLayer`, inside your `consumer`, you can check how many connections have been added to your channel layer with :

```
len(self.channel_layer.groups.get('room1', {}).items())
```

Comment: I got this error: 'RedisChannelLayer' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: Right, this is was tested using the `InMemoryChannelLayer`.